# Pandas GroupBy list with 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The original dataframe looks like this:

CSV data:

[image]

I got this data grouped with groupby, but only works with one column:

```
Worked hours   Tickets asociados
45453         [2023044087000705, 2023040487000059]
472335        [2023051187002601, 2023050587003176, 202305028...
```

I got this result by doing this

```
serieA = dfInforme.groupby("Worked hours")["Ticket number"].apply(list).reset_index(name="Tickets asociados")
```

But there is a column with a date value, and i want to display each ticket number in a row and in another column the date. Something like this.

```
Worked hours Date         Tickets asociados
45453        12/05/2023    2023044087000705
             05/05/2023    2023040487000059
472335       02/02/2023    2023050587003176
```

I was trying with:

```
serieA = dfInforme.groupby("Worked hours")[["Ticket number", "Date"]].apply(list).reset_index(name="Tickets asociados")
```

Thanks!

I tried to groupby with 2 columns but it isn't working as the lists are not hashable.

Comment: Please provide `dfInforme` in a reproducible format

Comment: Provided the csv format. DFinforme is just that csv being loaded with pd.read_csv('1.csv',sep=";")

Comment: An image is not reproducible. Also please ensure that the provided output matches what you would expect given your exact input

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for correctly, I believe you just need to add your `date` field to the `groupby`, as opposed to the aggregation in your example.

```
serieA = dfInforme.groupby(["Worked hours", "Date"])["Ticket number"].apply(list).reset_index(name="Tickets asociados")
```